# Create a question view that shows questions from multiple sites?

Tags: feature-request, multiple-accounts

Would it be possible to get a question view that shows questions from multiple sites?

Now that SE is splitting off into so many sites, I frequently find myself logging into 5+ sites to see what's new on each one.

It would be much easier if I could have a single question list which shows me questions from all the sites I'm interested in, and clicking on a question could still take me to the individual site.

I'd really only be interested in the New, Unanswered, and possibly Featured lists, and would want the ability to filter each site by tags.